# spring boot upload file over limit ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

1. Use spring boot initializer to create a simple project without using any other jars and redundant code (spring boot version 2.3.3 or spring boot version 2.7.3)
2. Write a simple file upload code
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sijxy.png)
3. Use the form to submit a file that exceeds the size limit (file size: 77.6 MB)

4.Browser error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH7UR.png)

5.The same error occurs when the same file is submitted using axios' ajax
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch8ET.png)

**6.But I can get the correct response when I use the postman request**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFH5y.png)

I don't know what the problem is??

1. I tried to track the spring boot code and found that the file upload logic was completed in the filter, and the error was thrown by tomcat

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (76822227) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.init(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.getMultiPartStream(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:194) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:213) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:131) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:255) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2869) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2771) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:87) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1178) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1012) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

2. I try to use other projects of the company for testing, and the same spring boot version (2.3.3) can get correct response results
3. Google Browser Version:  110.0.5481.100
   PostMan Version 10.9.4
   Aixos Version 0.18.1 or 0.21.4

Comment: Don't add pictures of text, they are not searchable.

Answer (score 1):

You should add CORS for SizeLimitExceededException exception handler:
https://mykb.cipindanci.com/archive/SuperKB/4477/

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.SizeLimitExceededException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
/**
 * Global Controller Exception Aspect
 * <p>
 * This handler only parse common exceptions, DON'T parse special exception here
 */
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> parseSizeLimitExceededException(SizeLimitExceededException exception, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");           // <--- here
    return logObject("File size exceed limitation: " + exception.getPermittedSize(), exception);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=-1` to ensure that the expception will be handled by Spring and a valid response returns. Otherwise Tomcat will reset the connection for large requests and the browser doesn't listen for the response anymore.

[Apache Tomcat Configuration - maxSwallowSize](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/config/http.html)

> The maximum number of request body bytes (excluding transfer encoding overhead) that will be swallowed by Tomcat for an aborted upload. An aborted upload is when Tomcat knows that the request body is going to be ignored but the client still sends it. If Tomcat does not swallow the body the client is unlikely to see the response. If not specified the default of 2097152 (2 MiB) will be used. A value of less than zero indicates that no limit should be enforced.

Unfortunately, I don't know why the behavior of the browser and Postman is different.

See links for more information:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maxuploadsizeexceeded#tomcat-configuration

Answer (score -1):

If you are uploading the file in MultipartFile format you can use the following properties in application.yaml file:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=300MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=300MB
```

If the file is extremely large you can send the data in chunks while uploading it.

Comment: I have tried the relevant configuration, but this is not the key to my question. Why can't I get the correct response when I use the form submission or ajax submission in the browser beyond the size of the uploaded file, while I can get the message of the server response in Postman

Comment: Try to track the API in the network tab of your browser by performing Fn + F12 in your browser weather your API is calling properly or not. There may be a possibility you are not calling the API properly from UI.